# Using googleVis api in java

Tags: r, dataset, java, google-sheets

I have used googleVis api in R for dynamic map.Now i am trying to make a small webapp in which servlet access this api and the result is displayed in jsp.But i am not able to access googleVis api from my servlet.Can some help me with it.